# Sending a confirmation mail to Email when registering

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, authentication

I want to send a confirmation email to a user who has just registered to the website. I googled it several times in order to find a solution but nothing worked so far.. Can you please help me with the code?
Thanks in advance!

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new     SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegisConnectionString"].ConnectionStr    ing);
        con.Open();
        string cmdStr = "Select count(*) from Table where Username='" +     TextBox1Username.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand userExist = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, con);
    /*  int temp = Convert.ToInt32(userExist.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        con.Close();
      if (temp == 1)
        {
            Response.Write("username already exists");
        } */
    }
}



protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection con = new     SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegisConnectionString"].ConnectionStr    ing);
    con.Open();
    string insCmd = "Insert into Register (Username, Password, EmailAddress,Fullname,     City) values (@Username, @Password, @EmailAddress, @Fullname, @City)";
    SqlCommand insertUser = new SqlCommand(insCmd, con);
    insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", TextBox1Username.Text);
    insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBox2Password.Text);
    insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", TextBox4Email.Text);
    insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fullname", TextBox5FullName.Text);
    insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", TextBox6City.Text);
    {
        try
        {

                insertUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");

        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            Response.Write("error: " + er.Message + " ,please try registering again");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That code has little to do with sending e-mails. What did you try and what happened?

Comment: I'm going to suggest this based on the fact you're 'new to asp .net', so I'm going to assume you haven't already heard about it. But asp .net comes with it's own membership 'system' which makes easy easy work of all of this stuff: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/342061/Understanding-ASP-NET-Roles-and-Membership-A-Begin As your question lacks a focus on one specific programming problem, I don't think you'll get a much more constructive suggestion for now.

Comment: If you have really googled you will find many articles a sample one is here http://articlemirror.blogspot.in/2013/06/how-to-send-email-with-verification.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simpliest solution for sending messages is via the first Google link on ASP.NET Mailing. I wonder what is not working for you with this:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx

I believe the object representation of MailMessage is pretty clear, otherwise it is all about SMTP settings.